# Where to find the third-party jars imported by spring source code

Tags: java, spring

When I was reading the spring source code(**version 5.0**), I found it imports some third-party jars. But I found no pom file in the package downloaded from github.
So where to find those jars, such as `rx.RxReactiveStreams` imported by `org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry`?

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to find the source of some class that's available in the general Java ecosystem, you can go to the [Central Repository](https://search.maven.org) and search there. The `fc:` option allows you to search by "full class name", and [searching `fc:rx.RxReactiveStreams`](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Arx.RxReactiveStreams) provides some good candidates, particularly `io-reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams`.